# Office Open XML SDK Spreadsheet how to display currency symbol in front of number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml

As you've read in the title, I've been looking for a way to format a spreadsheet cell with currency format. Using the code below I do get my currency format but the currency symbol is displayed after the numbers.

```
        // currency format
        stylesheet.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormats>().InsertAt<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat>(
           new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat()
           {
               NumberFormatId = 164,
               ApplyNumberFormat = true
           },
           8);
```

Does anyone know the NumberFormatId for currency format that display currency symbol in the front?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I need to add basic style to my spreadsheet. The code below adds basic style for currency.

```
// Currency
stylesheet.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.NumberingFormats>().InsertAt<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.NumberingFormat>(
  new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.NumberingFormat()
   {
     NumberFormatId = 164,
     FormatCode = "\"" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol + "\"\\ " + "#,##0.00"
   },0);
```

Thanks @Vadim for replying.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the XML code for this please? I am using Open XML to create spreadsheets and I wonder how the XML for representing currency types would look like? Pls help!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to improve above suggestion because I tried same and didn't get $ sign with negative value. I applied following changes and fixed the $ sign issue with negative values.

```
stylesheet.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.NumberingFormats>().InsertAt<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.NumberingFormat>(
  new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.NumberingFormat()
  {
    NumberFormatId = 164,
    FormatCode = "\"" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol + "\"\\ " + "#,##0.00;" + "\"(" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol + "\"\\ " + "#,##.00)[Red];0.00"

  }, 0);
```

Output :  for positive values $ 1.23
          for negative values ($ 1.23)    { font color is read)